# A comparison between the structures "would rather" and "would prefer"

Tags: sentence-structure, comparison, would-rather

I know that "i'd rather", like "I'd prefer" is used for specific situation and not general ones. On the other hand I know that the second sentence below doesn't work here. But the question ins that why the second sentence doesn't work here?

> **1 -** I’d prefer coffee to tea tonight.
>
> **2 -** I’d rather coffee to tea tonight.

My next question is that if "I'd rather" is in common use in AE.

Comment: You may infer from the relative lack of interest in [I'd rather not {do something} vs I'd prefer not to {do something}](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/42317/) as asked on ELU that's there's no generally-recognised clear-cut **semantic** distinction. If you want an easy life, assume they're exactly equivalent when trying to understand what someone else said/wrote. But only use ***prefer*** yourself, then you won't need to learn the slight *syntactic* differences that will mark you out as "non-native speaker" if you get them wrong.

Comment: As I see you mean that the nuances are too slight (perhaps difficult) to be understood; on the other point whereas based on each context they can vary in usage and a native can manipulate the sentence based on their instinct and use another one, then it doesn't worth to research to discover them. Am I right?

Comment: For your context, I really don't think there's much of a meaningful *semantic* difference between the two words. And of course they don't have *inherently different* meanings - it's just a matter of whether a significant number of native speakers recognise some slight distinction (which, frankly, they *don't*). So I suggest you forget about the semantics. If you're determined to use ***rather*** in your example (I'd advise not), you should note that *syntactically*, the vast majority of native speakers would use ***than*** rather than ***to*** in that exact context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[***prefer***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/prefer) indicates a choice of things (nouns), while [***rather***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/rather) indicates a choice of actions (verbs).
*Prefer* is a tr. verb and *rather* is an adverb.

So using your examples,

> 1 - I’d **prefer** coffee to tea tonight.

this is OK because it is used as a tr. verb.

> 2 - I'd **rather have** coffee to tea tonight.

Since *rather* is an adverb, a verb (both to be modified by the adverb, and just to have one in the sentence), is needed. In this case, *have*.

Comment: Also, _prefer_ goes with _to_, and _rather_ with _than_ (which you have incorrect in example 2).

Answer (score -1):

- I would rather have coffee than tea tonight.
  (Specific situation)
- I would prefer to have coffee to tea tonight.
  (Specific situation)
- I usually prefer having coffee to tea after breakfast. (Genaral daily routine of the speaker)

Comment: That seems a bit sparse. Can you edit to give more details of the rules here?